# Do mutable lambdas have their own copies of captured values?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
std::function<void()> create_function (args...)
{
    int x = initial_value (args...);

    return [x] () mutable
    {
        std::cout << x++ << std::endl;
    };
}
```

I discovered I need the `mutable` keyword on the lambda otherwise `x` is const.

If I call `create_function` multiple times, will the returned function objects each have their own copy of `x` or is it shared?

To clarify, If I wanted this kind of functionality pre-C++11, I would have to write a class to encapsulate the capture, in which case I would have a choice of making `x` a member variable or global/static. If `x` is const it wouldn't matter. How does the language specify the storage of `x` with respect to different instances of the lambda?

Comment: In short: Yes they do.

Comment: Lambdas do not have static capture.  There is no way to simulate your static members with lambdas. Which is jolly good because they ought to be thrown out of any code review, wuth prejudice.

Comment: It isn't actually at all clear how your static/global capture would function and in what scenarios it would be useful.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you. Can you cite the standard please?

Comment: There is no single phrase that says "there is no static/global capture in lambdas". It is simply not mentioned anywhere. To verify it you need to read the entire standard.

Answer (score 3):

`mutable` doesn't change if the captured values are value or reference. It only changes constness.

You specify if you want values (copies) or references in the lambda capture:

```
return [x] () mutable  // copies
{
    std::cout << x++ << std::endl;
};

return [&x] () mutable  // references
{
    std::cout << x++ << std::endl;
};
```

Lambda captures are always modeled as non-static data members, if that was your confusion.

Comment: That's a separate issue. Constness, value/reference, and shared/instance are all orthogonal.

Comment: @spraff lambda captures are per instance in C++. That's it. And that"s good.